# storing and object in a array with spring server NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a school project to create an website for buying movie tickets. The website will take the info you put into the input boxes and create an object and store it in an array on a spring server. But when I try to store it nothing happens and something is not working as intended. What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

```js
$(() => {
    $("#kjop").click (() => {
        const film = $("#film");
        const antall = $("#antall")
        const fornavn = $("#forNavn");
        const etternavn = $("#etterNavn");
        const telefon = $("#telefornr");
        const epost = $("#epost");

        const billett = {
            film: film.val(),
            antall: antall.val(),
            fornavn: fornavn.val(),
            etternavn: etternavn.val(),
            telefon: telefon.val(),
            epost: epost.val(),
        };

        if (inputval(billett)) {
            $.post("/billett", billett, () => hent());


            film.val("");
            antall.val("");
            fornavn.val("");
            etternavn.val("");
            telefon.val("");
            epost.val("");
        } else {
            console.log("Mangler input");
        }

        $("#slettBilett").click(() => {
            $.ajax("/billett", {
                type: "DELETE",
                success: () => hent(),
                error: (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) => console.log(errorMessage)
            });
        });
    });
});

const hent = () => $.get("/billett", billetter => utskrift (billetter));

const inputval => billett {
    if (billett.film === "") return false
    else if (billett.antall ==="") return false
    else if (billett.fornavn === "") return false
    else if (Billett.etternavn === "") return false
    else if (billett.telefon === "") return false
    else return billett.epost !== "";
}



const utskrift = billett => {
    let ut = "<table><tr>" +
        "<th>Film</th><th>antall</th><th>Navn</th><th>Etternavn</th><th>Telefonnr</th><th>Epost</th>" +
        "</tr>";
    for (let b of billett) {
        ut += "<tr>";
        ut += "<td>" + b.film + "</td><td>" + b.antall + "</td><td>" + b.navn + "</td><td>" + b.etternavn + "</td><td>" + b.tlf + "</td><td>" + b.epost + "</td>";
        ut += "</tr>";
    }
    ut += "</table>";
    $("#bestilt")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Oblig 1</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Bestilling av kinobiletter</h1>

<div>
    Velg film:
    <select id="film">
        <option value="non">Velg film her</option>
        <option>Iron man</option>
        <option>Troya</option>
        <option>Avengers</option>
        <option>The green mile</option>
        <option>God father</option>
        <option>Fight club</option>
    </select><span id="valgterr" style = "color:#ff0000"></span>
</div>

<br /><br />

<div>
    Antall <input type="text" id="antall" /><span id="antallerr" style = "color:red"> </span>
</div>

<br /><br />

<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Fornavn</td><td> <input type="text" id="forNavn" /> </td><td><span id="forNavnerr" style = "color:red"> </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Etternavn</td><td> <input type="text" id="etterNavn"/> </td><td><span id="etterNavnerr" style = "color:red"> </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Telefonnr</td><td> <input type="text" id="telefornr"/> </td><td><span id="tlferr" style = "color:red"> </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Epost</td><td> <input type="text" id="epost"/> </td><td><span id="eposterr" style = "color:red"> </span></td>
    </tr>


</table>

<button onclick="kjop();">Kjøp Billet</button>

<br /><br />

<h2>
    Alle Billetter
</h2>
<div id="bestilt">
</div>
<br /><br />
<button onclick="slettBilett();">Slett alle billetter</button>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.billett;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Repository
public class AppRepository {
    private final ArrayList<billett> billettliste = new ArrayList<>();

    public void leggInn(billett billett) {
        billettliste.add(billett);
    }

    public ArrayList<billett> hentAlle () {
        return billettliste;
    }

    public void slettBilett() {
        billettliste.clear();
    }
}
```

```html
package com.example.demo;


import com.example.demo.billett;
import com.example.demo.AppRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/lagringserver/")
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    AppRepository repo;

    @PostMapping("/billett")
    public void lagre(billett billett) {
                repo.leggInn(billett);
            }
    @GetMapping("/billett")
    public ArrayList<billett> hent() {
        return repo.hentAlle();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/billett")
    public void slett() {
        repo.slettBilett();
    }
}
```

```html
package com.example.demo;

public class billett {
    private String film;
    private String antall;
    private String fornavn;
    private String etternavn;
    private String telefon;
    private String epost;

        public billett (String film, String antall, String fornavn, String etternavn, String telefon, String epost) {
            this.film = film;
            this.antall= antall;
            this.fornavn = fornavn;
            this.etternavn = etternavn;
            this.telefon = telefon;
            this.epost = epost;
        }

        public String getFilm() {
            return film;
        }

        public void setFilm(String film){
            this.film = film;
        }
        public String getAntall(){
            return antall;
        }

        public void setAntall(String fornavn){
            this.antall = antall;
        }

        public String getFornavn(){
            return fornavn;
        }

        public void setFornavn(String fornavn){
            this.fornavn = fornavn;
        }
        public String getEtternavn(){
            return etternavn;
        }

        public void setEtternavn (String etternavn){
            this.etternavn = etternavn;
        }
        public String getTelefon(){
            return telefon;
        }

        public void setTelefon (String telefon){
            this.telefon = telefon;
        }
        public String getEpost(){
            return epost;
        }

        public void setepost (String epost){
            this.epost = epost;
        }

    }
```